# get unique contents of div with same class name

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to capture a value from a table on a click event.

```
events: {           
'click  .serial': 'parseSerialNo'
},

parseSerialNo: function(){
    var serialNo = $('.serial').text();
    console.log(serialNo);
},
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 serial">0005550</div>
<div class="col-md-4 serial">0008650</div>
<div class="col-md-4 serial">0067860</div>
```

what is the best way to grab the unique content within the div? Currently .text() returns all content in serial div (as it should). Do I need a this somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter event to the function and then get the element with currentTarget attribute

```
  parseSerialNo: function(e){
        var serialNo =$(e.currentTarget).text(); //get current target of event
        console.log(serialNo);
    },
```